# Notification cancel problem

Tags: android, notifications

I want to delete all the notification that are present in the top bar. For that I use the following code.

```
notification = (NotificationManager) mContextNotification.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if(mNotificationManager != null)
  mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
```

But no notification is deleting from the bar. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `notification` but trying to use `mNotificationManager`?

I personally had no trouble removing all notifications when my app is resumed:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

The mNotificationManager is declared like yours (only called the correct thing). It should never be null if you create it with the system service in onCreate like that and do the cancel on it some time later.

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake in code. I have corrected it now. But it is not working